# Finding Gridlayout in a Fragment

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments

I have been trying to figure out how to find a Gridlayout in a fragment using findViewById. I've looked everywhere and am surprised to not have found this instructed by anyone in a similar situation of mine. I have used a tab layout in android studios, the tabs are different fragments, and within them are Gridlayouts which have cardviews that open new activities. I have provided the code below to show what I am working with:

```
public class PCpage extends Fragment {

GridLayout pcGrid;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View mainPc = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pc_main, container, false);
    return mainPc;

    pcGrid = (GridLayout) mainPc.findViewById(R.id.pcGrid);

    setSingleEvent(pcGrid);

}

private void setSingleEvent(GridLayout pcGrid){
    for(int i =0; i<pcGrid.getChildCount();i++){
        CardView cardView = (CardView)pcGrid.getChildAt(i);
        final int acterI = i;
        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(acterI == 0){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(PCpage.this.getActivity(), Parsecards.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else if(acterI == 1){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(PCpage.this.getActivity(), Parsecards.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
        });
    }
  }
}
```

The following line doesn't seem to want to work out and is returning an error "unreachable statement":

```
pcGrid = (GridLayout) mainPc.findViewById(R.id.pcGrid);
```

Any feedback on why this is happening or how to fix this and make it work would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Anything after your `return` statement will not be executed; the method returns a value and completes. Move the line to somewhere before your `return` statement.

Comment: Wow how did I not think of that. Stupid mistake, been looking at this for way too long. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Don't forget to drink coffee and trace flow of execution.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning mainPc before doing this:

```
pcGrid = (GridLayout) mainPc.findViewById(R.id.pcGrid);

setSingleEvent(pcGrid);
```

so just move the `return mainPc` as the last line in the onCreateView

Answer (score 0):

i think you must put this line :

```
return mainPc;
```

after this line :

```
setSingleEvent(pcGrid);
```